# What does it mean : "Property type "JSQMessagesCollectionView" is incompatible with type "UICollectionView", inherited from "UICollectionViewLayout"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I'm currently coding an iOS app in Swift, and I use some stuff like JSQMessages and JSQSystemSoundPlayer in Objective C.

When I introduced them in my code, I had the Xcode 6.2, and it worked perfectly.
I downloaded Xcode 6.3.4 to use Swift 1.2, but now I have 40 warnings like :

"Property type "JSQMessagesCollectionView" is incompatible with type "UICollectionView", inherited from "UICollectionViewLayout""

I already made a Bridging Header to call the Objective C files.

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is not the place for such a question. You should open an issue with the GitHub tracker for this project: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController

Comment: This is not a problem related to JSQMessages I would like to know, just what does mean this error (it could be my own code, it worked for Xcode 6.2, but not in Xcode 6.3.4), thanks Leo

Comment: I removed the downvote. I thought you were complaining about the warning, instead of looking to learn about it, sorry about that. See my answer.

Comment: Please answer this question if anyone knows that issue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31153071/jsqmessagesviewcontroller-in-swift-with-xcode-6-3-objective-c-selector-issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the comments, here is the explanation of what this warning is.

Xcode 6.3 has an updated compiler toolchain, which is more strict, thus you are seeing more warnings in general, including this one.

Here, the class `JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout` declares a property whose definition conflicts with its superclass' definition:

```
@property (readonly, nonatomic) JSQMessagesCollectionView *collectionView;
```

Whereas, in the superclass, `UICollectionViewLayout`, it is declared as:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) UICollectionView *collectionView;
```

Objective C does not support property [covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29), and this override is an incorrect use of the language by Jesse. The `JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout` class should expose an additional property which is of the subclass type.

Comment: Thanks a lot Leo for the answer, I'm sorry if I was not clear and you thought I was just complaining.

Answer (score 0):

in order to remove this warning, just remove `@property (readonly, nonatomic) JSQMessagesCollectionView *collectionView;` from its class `JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout.h` to `JSQMessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout.m`