# JSQMessagesViewController in Swift with Xcode 6.3 Objective-C Selector issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am using JSQMessagesViewController in swift with Xcode 6.3
Any one know about this error? how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: When I am removing these func or rename this, this error will occur 'ChatMessagesViewController' does not conform to protocol 'JSQMessagesCollectionViewDataSource'

Comment: did you try replacing `String` with `NSString` in return type of these functions?

Comment: yes, still same error

Answer (score 0):

Declare this as a Type function by using `class func` as such:

```
 class func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "Dan"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should assign the values of both senderId and senderDisplayName in the viewDidLoad(), instead of methods.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.senderId = "YOUR_SENDER_ID"
    self.senderDisplayName = "YOUR_DISPLAY_NAME"

}
```